# CSS alignment/positioning for title

Tags: css, position

I'm coding a beta version of my website and I have a problem currently that I want to fix.

I want to use CSS to make the following code;

```
<div class="title">
                <div class="l_bracket">{</div>
                <div class="my_name">Sean Arnold</div>
                <div class="dev_student">Developer&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Student</div>
                <div class="r_bracket">}</div>
            </div>
```

look like this:

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: your question is not clear, what is the problem? is below line is extra indent toward right?

Comment: I just didn't know how to write the css for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

title should have a background color black and the font-color should be set to gray.

l_bracket should have a float: left
r_bracket should have a float: right.

You have to experiment with the sizes of my_name and dev_student.

If you want to see what you are doing and how the div are sized etc. install firebug.